# Facebook Android SDK 3.0 callback not called on cancel

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to upgrade an existing app/framework with Facebook Android SDK v3.0 but am stuck on how to authenticate with extra permissions.

The problem is that the StatusCallback does not seem to fire if the user cancels.  If I use the regular call to `Session.openActiveSession` the callback fires on cancel, but using a new `Session.OpenRequest` on fresh `Session` object does not.

Here's my code:

```
Session.OpenRequest auth = new Session.OpenRequest(this);

String[] permissions = {"publish_stream", "user_status"};

auth.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(permissions));

auth.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);

auth.setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        switch(state) {

            case OPENING:
                System.out.println("OPENING");
                break;              

            case OPENED: // <-- NOT CALLED
                System.out.println("OPENED");
                break;

            case CREATED: // <-- NOT CALLED
                System.out.println("CREATED");
                break;

            case CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED: // <-- NOT CALLED
                System.out.println("CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED");
                break;

            case OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED: // <-- NOT CALLED
                System.out.println("OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED");
                break;

            case CLOSED: // <-- NOT CALLED
                System.out.println("CLOSED");
                break;      

            case CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED: // <-- NOT CALLED
                System.out.println("CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED");
                break;                          
        }
    }
});

Session session = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId("<My APP ID>").build();
session.openForPublish(auth);
```

This produces a view on the device like this:

http://cl.ly/image/0E2C0t2m2b0g

(FB app is not installed).  If the user clicks the close button (top left) the callback is NOT triggered.

If I use the `Session.openActiveSession` in the same scenario the callback IS triggered.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem.  When creating a session manually, one must set this session as the "active session" on the static Session instance:

```
Session session = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId("<My APP ID>").build();
Session.setActiveSession(session); // <-- MUST DO THIS
session.openForPublish(auth);
```