# Facebook Session cancel dialog

Tags: android, facebook, events, dialog

I'm developping an app that uses this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/native-login/

I have followed the Facebook dev tutorial, so basically I have the session check, it opens the dialog, and I'm trying to get the Cancel event (when the user cancel the facebook dialog) but I have no method on this.

Maybe you can help.

Thanks

EDIT: Actually, even if I click the cancel button, I still receive the GraphUser correctly. That's weird.

Comment: Let's talk here: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36809/facebook-session-cancel-dialog).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Android SDK 3.5, I got the cancel event via exception, if the state change callback with instance of FacebookOperationCanceledException or FacebookAuthorizationException, its an cancel event:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException || exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {

        // Cancelled by user, show alert
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.cancelled).setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();

    } else {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if ((session != null && session.isOpened())) {
            // Session ready
        }
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

It works just great

Comment: Actually, no it's not working. I'm always getting inside the if (exception...). Never in the else.

Comment: Since you are always getting into the if, lets check if it is an FacebookAuthorizationException but not FacebookOperationCanceledException?

It could be possible that you did not set your Key Hashes correctly in your FB app setting.

Comment: Look at the getting started correctly, for step 4 and 5:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/

Comment: Okay now I got it right, but if the user clics on Cancel, I want to finish the activity that calls the facebook dialog. But finish() isn't doing the job.

Comment: You are calling in an activity or fragment? if activity, replace the alert with finish(); should work. Else getActivity().finish();

Comment: None is working. Not even the MyActivity.this.finish(). I'll look into it today

Comment: It works just great!.. please update that: `FacebookOperationCanceledException` or `FacebookAuthorizationException` also detect the cancel button of publish permissions requests as well so in order to differentiate between cancel of login or cancel of publishing use `if(session.isOpen())` then it is cancel for publishing otherwise it is cancel for login.

Comment: @JarodLaw I am always getting CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED state even allowing access to fb dialog (Only with SSO). I also double checked all the key hashes. Please help me to figure out this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Session.StatusCallback to your open request where you can check the SessionState.

```
       new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        //check state
            }

        };
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571870/facebook-android-sdk-3-0-callback-not-called-on-cancel).

Comment: It's not exactly the same problem he has. I'm actually having problem handling the "Cancel" button on the native dialog.